# What is a Dual Of a Line Segment?

Tags: geometry, duality-theorems

According to duality, dual of a line is a point. If there is a point p(x,y) exists in a plane, If i take dual of this I will get $ax + by = 1$ a line.
But what will be the dual of a line segment. Will it be a point?. Is there any Mathematical proof to it? Or any such theorems exist?

Answer (score 0):

It is also a line segment.

The dual of an $n$-dimensional polytope $P$ has a face of dimension $n-d-1$ for each $d$-dimensional face of $P$. You can see that clearly for the cube and octahedron. The eight vertices of the cube (dimension $0$) give the eight faces of the octahedron (dimension $3-0-1=2$). The twelve edges of each naturally correspond.

On the line, with dimension $1$, each of the two endpoints of a segment, with dimension $0$, gives a face of the dual of dimension $1-0-1 = 0$, which is just a point. The dual has two points, so is a line segment.

Or in projective geometry, it is a wedge between two lines.

Comment: You are stating dual of a line segment is a line. But according to the formula n-d-1 it is coming as 1-0-1 = 0 for line segment also, So it is coming as a point right?

Answer (score 0):

The dual of a line segment is a left-right double wedge. When a line segment is mapped from the primal to the dual what is created is a bounded region. To understand this lets first consider what a line segment is, it's a line between two points. Thus the end-points are mapped to two lines and the line itelf is mapped to the point where the two lines intersect, due to incidence preservation. The region that is bounded represent all the points on the line segment, with the geometric interpratation: since the x-coordinate determines the slope and the line segement is continuous, it's like taking a line and rotating it.